# Python: Unexpected behavior when function argument is replicated list of lists

Tags: python, list, function, arguments

Lists by being mutable objects when called are passing reference (which if my understanding is correct is essentially passing id's).  In the code below I assign a list of lists A. I call it into a function named modify(M) that modifies M. As expected A and M have the same id's and modifying M also modifies A. So far so good.

However, I then reassign A into the original value (as expected changing its id). Then I call modify(A*1), i.e. passing as argument a replicated A.  As expected, now A and M have different id's and M is A returns False.  **However, changing M still changes A**, contrary to my expectation that it would not.  Why is that?

Note: Calling modify(A[:]) also gives the same unexpected (by me) behavior.

I know that the answer has to do with that I have a list of lists.  (When I try this with just one-level lists I get the behavior I expected.)

As I am a relative beginner to Python coding, I would very much appreciate an answer that a beginner might understand.

Here is the code:

```
def modify(M):
    print(M is A)
    print('id of M', id(M))
    print('id of A', id(A))
    print('Original list of lists before change in M =', A)
    M[0][0]=M[1][1] #some modification of M
    print('Original list of lists after change in M =', A)
    print(M is A)
    print('id of M', id(M))
    print('id of A', id(A))

A=[[1,2],[3,42]]
modify(A)    #Argument is the list 
print("\n","*****What happens below is driving me crazy!*****","\n")
A=[[1,2],[3,42]]
modify(A*1)  #Argument is replicated list of lists
#modify(A[:]) has the same behavior
```

**EDIT: I just made a discovery that does not answer the question for me, but probably answers the question for someone more adept in Python than I am.**

It requires that you import copy.

1. Replace `modify(A*1)` with `modify(copy.copy(A))`.  Exactly the same strange behavior is observed.  In other words, the id's become different, yet A changes when M changes.
2. Replace `modify(A*1)` with `modify(deepcopy.copy(A))`.  What I expected happens.  In other words, the id's become different, and A does not change when M changes.

Comment: Does this same thing happen if you use immutable data structures as arguments (like a tuple)

Comment: Good question.  Of course the code crashes if A is assigned as a tuple of tuples.  But if you assign A as a tuple of lists A=([1,2],[3,42]),  A again changes when M changes, but now A and M have the same ids

Comment: Yeah I meant a tuple of tuples

Comment: For a tuple of tuples you are trying to modify a tuple and you get the TypeError:   File "L:\__Transfer\test0008.py", line 13, in modify
    M[0][0]=M[1][1] #some modification of M

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Yeah you’d have to make copies of objects

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out an answer to my question which was:

Then I call modify(A*1), i.e. passing as argument a replicated A. As expected, now A and M have different id's and M is A returns False. **However, changing M still changes A**, contrary to my expectation that it would not. Why is that?

Answer:
The list of lists has an id.  But also the items of the second level lists have their own id's.  I edited the code to also print the id's of the second level items M[0][0] and M[1][1]:

```
def modify(M):
    print(M is A)
    print('id of M and list items', id(M), id(M[0][0]), id(M[1][1]))
    print('id of A and list items', id(A), id(A[0][0]), id(A[1][1]))
    print('Original list of lists before change in M =', A)
    M[0][0]=M[1][1] #some modification of M`
    print('Original list of lists after change in M =', A)
    print(M is A)
    print('id of M and list items', id(M), id(M[0][0]), id(M[1][1]))
    print('id of A and list items', id(A), id(A[0][0]), id(A[1][1]))

A=[[1,2],[3,42]]
modify(A)    #Argument is the list 
print("\n","*****What happens below is driving me crazy!*****","\n")
A=[[1,2],[3,42]]
modify(A*1)  #Argument is replicated list of lists
#modify(A[:]) has the same behavior`
```

And here is the printout:

True
id of M and list items 2436965208832 140725589391136 140725589392448
id of A and list items 2436965208832 140725589391136 140725589392448
Original list of lists before change in M = [[1, 2], [3, 42]]
Original list of lists after change in M = [[42, 2], [3, 42]]
True
id of M and list items 2436965208832 140725589392448 140725589392448
id of A and list items 2436965208832 140725589392448 140725589392448

*****What happens below is driving me crazy!*****

False
**id of M and list items 2436965208832 140725589391136 140725589392448

id of A and list items 2436956205440 140725589391136 140725589392448**
Original list of lists before change in M = [[1, 2], [3, 42]]
Original list of lists after change in M = [[42, 2], [3, 42]]
False
id of M and list items 2436965208832 140725589392448 140725589392448
id of A and list items 2436956205440 140725589392448 140725589392448

The first call `modify(A)` as expected resulted in an M that not only has the same id as A but also all its items have the same id as their counterparts in A.  However, the second call `modify(A*1)` produces an M that has a different id from A but **the id's of the items M[0][0] and M[1][1] remain the same as those of A[0][0] and A[1][1], respectively.**  That's why assigning a new value to M[0][0] assigns the same value to A[0][0].  That's why the strange behavior was observed.

Lesson learned: Two lists with different id's may have components that share memory address.  So having `list1 is list2` resolve as `False` does not guarantee that changes in components of list1 will not change corresponding components of list2. For some reason the replicate *1 command changes the id's of the list but not of the second level items.